# Error in a plot with constraints

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a function `f[x_, y_] = x Sqrt[x^4 + y^4]`. I want to plot this function and also the regions `z >= x + y - 1; z <= 1 - x + y; z <= x + y - 1; z >= 1 + x - y;`. Here is an attempt which leads to some errors:

```
 region = ImplicitRegion[{z >= x + y - 1, z <= 1 - x + y, 
    z <= x + y - 1, z >= 1 + x - y}, {x, y, z}];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, region]]
```

How can one resolve this?

Comment: `Plot3D[x Sqrt[x^4 + y^4], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, -1 + x + y <= z <= 1 - x + y]]` works. Are you sure about the constraints you're using? (Look at the result of `Region[ImplicitRegion[And @@ {z >= x + y - 1, z <= 1 - x + y, z <= x + y - 1, z >= 1 + x - y}, {x, y, z}]]`, for instance.)

Comment: For the given range of `x` and `y`, evaluate `Reduce[z >= x + y - 1 && z <= 1 - x + y && z <= x + y - 1 && z >= 1 + x - y && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1]` to see that your region is a line in the `y == 1` plane: `0 <= z <= 1 && y == 1 && x == z`

Comment: Actually my constraint is $(x \pm y)^2 \le (1 \pm z)^2$ which (if I am correct) results in the four inequalities I mentioned.

Comment: @User101 the $\pm$ symbol is ambiguous.

Comment: Is `Plot3D[x Sqrt[x^4 + y^4], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, (x + y)^2 <= (1 + z)^2 && (x - y)^2 <= (1 - z)^2]]` what you were expecting, then?